# Why am I getting this error, eventhough I am getting result?

Tags: java, substring, runtime-error, runtimeexception, stringindexoutofbounds

Getting exception in  the code below:

```
import java.io.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    FileReader objRead = new FileReader("/home/acer/Desktop/sulabh");
    BufferedReader objB = new BufferedReader(objRead);
    String input = null;
    while((input=objB.readLine())!= null){
        String temp = input.substring(0,2);
       if(temp.contains("77")) {
           System.out.println(input);
       }
    }
    objB.close();
}
```

And error with the answer is:
777
777

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 2, length 0 at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319) at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874) at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: Use `System.out.println(input)` to test what you're actually reading

Comment: What is your input file

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs for substring:

```
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.
```

Your `String temp = input.substring(0,2);` is getting a line shorter than length 2 after it gets the two good lines.

Protect against that as follows.

```
String temp = "";

if (input.length()>=2){
temp = input.substring(0,2);
}
```

Comment: Or get rid of temp and say if (input.indexOf("77")==0)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first two lines have been processed fine and it throws error for the blank line at the end. Please check if you have a blank line at the end of the file. The blank line may contain less than 2 chractors.

Alternatively you can try `input.startsWith("77")` as well